# Move only the files in sub folders to a target folder

Tags: linux, files, mv

Directories

```
/dropbox/input/abc/file1.txt
/dropbox/input/pqr/file2.txt
/dropbox/input/lmn/file3.txt
/dropbox/input/xyz/file4.txt
```

How to move only the files from the folders `/dropbox/input/`?

similar to `mv /dropbox/input/` ... (only files from sub folders) to `/project/input/`

Comment: do you want to keep the source directory structure, or move every file (risking collisions) into /project/input?

Comment: Also, you list a heading of "directories" but then list things that look like files. Do you have a directory named `/dropbox/input/pqr/file2.txt`?  Also, you show a nested directory structure but then ask "How to move only the files from the folder(s) `/dropbox/input` -- while not showing any files directly in that directory.  Can you spell out your situation with some clearer examples, please?

Comment: You might be vaguely interested in `find`'s `-mindepth` parameter.

Comment: In your example there are no files in `/dropbox/input/` to move.  Or did you intend to ask how to move all the files under `/dropbox/input` _and its subdirectories_?

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
find /dropbox/input -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type f -exec mv '{}' /project/input \;
```

The "mindepth" and "maxdepth" options will limit the results of find to files that are within subdirectories of your "input" directory, but not the "input" directory itself and not in sub-sub directories. Try it first without the "-exec" portion to see if it lists the files you intended:

```
find /dropbox/input -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type f
```

Comment: Also `mv -t /project/input {} \+`

Comment: This worked for me...Thank you -->> find /dropbox/input -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type f -exec mv '{}' /project/input \;

Answer (score 1):

```
(cd /dropbox/input && find -type f -path './*/*' -print0 | xargs -r0 -0 mv -t /project/input)
```